# Оператор using в C#

Tags: c#

Использую оператор [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx) следующим образом:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    // ...
    reader.Close();
}
```

В строке инициализации возникает исключение `FileNotFoundException`

> Could not find file '...'.

которое выкидывает конструктор [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx), после чего программа завершается. Вопрос: разве оператор using не включает сам по себе обработку исключения по умолчанию (вызов Dispose) и нужно самостоятельно его обрабатывать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, using никаких исключений не обрабатывает, для этого следует использовать try/catch блоки.

Answer (score 4):

**Оператор using гарантирует вызов метода Dispose, даже если при вызове методов в объекте происходит исключение**, потому что using это ничто иное как try/finally блоки. Но сам по себе он никаких исключений не обрабатывает.